# Reading data from a microphone in android to process it online

Tags: android, audio, microphone

I have a problem reading audiodata from microphone in android. My app must change lightness of a logo picture depending on volume of a sound, which I read from microphone. I use AudioRecord class to get audiodata. Depending on sample rate and buffer size, every 2nd/4th/8th read operation goes with latency of 100-200 ms. So my app can't react on volume changes properly. I tried to reduce buffer size, and to execute data processing in other thread (using AudioRecord.setPositionNotificationPeriod() and callback) but those not make much sense - latency just becomes a little shorter. Here is my code:

```
package com.mikesoft.Clown;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder.AudioSource;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.lang.Math;

public class TestActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnRecordPositionUpdateListener {

private static final String LOG_TAG = TestActivity.class.getSimpleName();

//arrays for selecting usable audioformat
private static int[] mSampleRates = new int[] {8000, 11025, 22050, 44100};
private static short[] audioFormat = new short[] {AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT};
private static short[] channelConfig = new short[] {AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO};

private short[][] buffers;
private int ix;

private AudioRecord recorder = null;
private int bufferSize = 0;
private AudioThread recordingThread = null;
private boolean isRecording = false;
/** The OpenGL View */
private LogoView glSurface;

//markers
private short[] buffer;
private long read_time;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_test);
    findViewById(R.id.btnStart).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.btnStop).setOnClickListener(this);
    mVolumeText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.volume);

    setRecordMode();

    glSurface = (LogoView)findViewById(R.id.glSurface);
}

private void setRecordMode() {
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop)).setClickable(isRecording);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart)).setClickable(!isRecording);
}

public void startRecording() {
    if (null == recorder) {
        recorder = findAudioRecord();

        recorder.setRecordPositionUpdateListener(this);

        recorder.startRecording();

        isRecording = true;

        recordingThread = new AudioThread();
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Audio recording started");
}

//thread for executing audio recorder
private class AudioThread extends Thread {

    private AudioThread() {
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
        recordAudio();
    }

}

private void recordAudio() {
        ix = 0;
    int read = 0;
    recorder.setPositionNotificationPeriod(bufferSize);
    while (isRecording) {
        //long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        buffer = buffers[ix++ % buffers.length];
        read = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        //time after reading
        //read_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "read bytes: " + read);
        //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "read_time=" + (read_time - t1));

        //int vol = 0;
        //for (int i=0;i<buffer.length;i++) 
        //  vol = Math.max(vol, Math.abs(buffer[i]));
        //float norm = (float)vol/(float)Short.MAX_VALUE;
        //glSurface.setLightness(norm);
    }
}

//initialize AudioRecord with suitable format
public AudioRecord findAudioRecord() {
    //for (int rate : mSampleRates) {
    int rate = 22050;
        for (short format : audioFormat) {
            for (short channel : channelConfig) {
                try {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Attempting rate " + rate + "Hz, bits: " + audioFormat + ", channel: "
                            + channelConfig);
                    bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, channel, format);

                    if (bufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                        // check if we can instantiate and have a success
                        AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, rate, channel, format, bufferSize);
                            //bufferSize/=8;
                        if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
                            buffers = new short[256][bufferSize];
                            return recorder;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, rate + "Exception, keep trying.",e);
                }
            }
        }
        //}
        return null;
}

public void stopRecording() {
    if (null != recorder) {
        isRecording = false;

        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();

        recorder = null;
        recordingThread = null;
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Audio recording stopped");
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnStart:
        startRecording();
        setRecordMode();
        break;
    case R.id.btnStop:
        stopRecording();
        setRecordMode();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}

@Override
public void onMarkerReached(AudioRecord arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onPeriodicNotification(AudioRecord arg0) {
    float norm;
    short[] buf = buffers[ix % buffers.length];
    int vol = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++)
        vol = Math.max(vol, Math.abs(buf[i]));
    norm = (float) vol / (float) Short.MAX_VALUE;
    glSurface.setLightness(norm);
}

}
```

I tried devices&emulators with Android 1.6-3.2 but it's the same thing everywhere. Is there a solution for my problem in Java? Or I should use NDK approaches?
Will appreciate any help.